# Multiple Relations between two Entities?

Tags: entity-relationship

I am just confused that can there should be multiple Relationships between two Entities?

I am building a ER Model for a Social Networking Website.

and I come across a problem where I have two tables "User" and "Post", and User can view, share, like a post.

```
User <view> Post
User <share> Post
User <likes> Post
```

Is this possible in ER Diagram?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get more specific about what kind of relationship each one is.  For example, I would assume the View relationship is a many-to-many (a user can view many posts, a post can be viewed by many users) so there needs to be another table between the two.  I think the same would also be true for the Likes relationship.

For Shares it depends, can a user share posts other than their own?  If so then this sounds like another many-to-many relationship.  If not then maybe "shared" is an attribute of the Post entity and not a relationship (the relationship would be User owns/created Post).